# jQuery Mobile Select all a Tags in all Pages

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile

How can you select all `<a>` tags in jQuery Mobile if you have more pages?

I tried it with `jQuery("a")`

Comment: So what's your question? Can you explain it in detail? jQuery("a"); works fine... or you can use $("a");

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to select elements on pages that aren't currently loaded? That's not possible. If you have pages that are being loaded dynamically (e.g. via AJAX) and need to process something on those pages, then take a look at the JQuery .live() event, which will kick off whenever new content is loaded within a selected element.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these `<a>` tags after you select them?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of jQuery [Mobile] you use you should be able to bind an event to items that don't (yet) exist on the page with either the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and the on method is preferred.

The [live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will bind an event to the `document` and execute it when the event is triggered on an element matching the given selector:

```
$("a").live('click', function () { /* do something on click with the 'a' element clicked */ });
```

The [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is better since it doesn't depend the even bubbling up to the document before executing.

Instead you put the event on a parent object of the elements that will be created in the future but already exists and you supply a selector to specify which elements within that selector 'qualify' to get the event called on. In your case to select all 'a' tags on the page, doing the same as the above code:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a', function () { /* do something on click with the 'a' element clicked */ });
```

If you want to do something with the a tags as soon as they are loaded through ajax you should do this in the complete callback for your ajax request loading them. This can possibly be done by appending the `.done(callback)` to your `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` request.

Please read [the documentation for a good explanation on `.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

- [Read more about even bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)
- [Documentation on the live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [Documentation on the on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)